# Define \def commands which expand non-static

Tags: macros

I have two new commands like

```
\def\test[#2]#1{
\test#1[#2]
}

\def\testOne[#2]{
#2 is given
}
```

if I use the following command `\test[xy]{One}`, it doesn't work, because `\test#1[#2]` expands to `\test{#1}[#2]`. So it expands to `\test{One}[xy]` instead of `testOne[xy]`.

Is there any possibility, to make this work?

Comment: `\def\test[#1]#2{\csname test#2\endcsname{#1}}`

Comment: I think @UlrikeFischer actually meant `\def\test[#1]#2{\csname test#2\endcsname[#1]}`.  But note that you must say `\def\testOne[#1]{#1 is given}`, because argument must be numbered in progression.  May I ask why the square brackets?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: That's exactly, what I was looking for, thanks. If you want to post it as an answer, go ahead, otherwise, I will post it as a solution. `\csname` was,what I was looking for. From now on, I can goolge the rest of it.
@GustavoMezzetti: I used the correct numbering in my tex-document. I changed it here for readability, but thanks for this useful advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UlrikeFischer and GustavoMezzetti answered the (actually simple) question. Thanks a lot.

The code must be

```
\def\test[#1]#2{\csname test#2\endcsname[#1]}
```